# Correspondence of an ensemble

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

Let $\mathcal{E} = \{ p_i, \psi_i \}$ be an ensemble of quantum states where $p$ is a probability distribution, what exactly is its physical and mathematical correspondence?

Is it a mixed state where $\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i \rangle \langle \psi_i|$,

or a "flagged" state where $\rho = \sum_i p_i |i \rangle \langle i| \otimes |\psi_i \rangle \langle \psi_i|$,

or a product state $\bigotimes_i |\psi_i \rangle \langle \psi_i|^{\otimes p_i N}$ for some large number $N$, of identical independent systems?

The above are all viable structures $\mathcal{E}$ can be mapped to, sometimes it feels as though people can be referring to any one of these cases, but which one is it? Maybe this is common knowledge, but it seems to be rarely spoken of.

Comment: Could you define what $p_i$ and $\psi_i$ are? Context is important.

Comment: the first one is the only way I've seen such an ensemble defined. Where did you see the other definitions?

Comment: @glS: 3rdly, $\mathcal{E}$ is often physically examplarized by a particle stream of electrons/photons. Say, let $\mathcal{E}=\{(p_1,\rho_1=|\uparrow\rangle),(p_2,\rho_2=|\downarrow\rangle),(p_3,\rho_3=\alpha|\uparrow\rangle + \beta|\downarrow\rangle)\}$. Sometimes, it is described as: the next particle generated can be in the given states with such probabilities. Othertimes, I am under the impression: of the $N$ particles generated in some time-lapse, $p_i N$ are in the state $\rho_i$. If so, then it should be the 3rd form, as they are different systems and not "parts of trace".

Comment: Note, $p_i N$ is rounded to an integer, so it represents the number of systems.

Comment: @glS: 1stly, if the ensemble is the mixed state, then why not write it so? Also, a mixed state can have many ensemble decompositions (1-to-many). 2ndly, regarding your question (2nd form), I read entanglement does not increase under mixing (information loss), to give an operational description, states in $\mathcal{E}$ are paired to classical pointers, forgetting (tracing out) the pointers does not generate entanglement (as summarized by chitambar2019 p10). This yields a 1-to-1 correspondence to $\mathcal{E}$, which is arguably better.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. An ensemble $\mathcal E=\{(p_i,\rho_i)\}_i$ *by definition* is/corresponds to the state $\sum_i p_i\rho_i$. I trust any textbook using the notation will define it as such? Can you link sources that don't? That the state can have different decompositions is besides the point. I also don't see how entanglement enters this discussion. If you are asking the usefulness of talking about state ensembles, that's fine, but that's not what the post is currently asking about

Comment: or if you are asking whether those forms are equivalent, no they are not. If you partial trace the second form wrt the first space you get the first form, but the overall states are still clearly not the same. The third form is just a completely different type of state. It refers to having multiple copies of different states, rather than a single copy of a system whose state you are uncertain about

Comment: @glS: Textbook definition is one thing, practical use is another. There's visibly a discrepancy between the various descriptions of an ensemble (I am well aware of obviously), see if you can address my particle stream example. Moreover, given a mixed state, you don't get the partition of an ensemble, which is why I used entanglement to introduce the 2nd form, how it's the operational precursor to a mixed state. My observation is the ensemble is a loose description, can refer to all of the forms given, which are concrete representations with physical correspondences. I only wish to confirm it.

Comment: there is visibly a discrepancy between the states you wrote in the questions, sure, but only one of them is related to what the ensemble $\mathcal E$ is. The other states are unrelated. Regarding the particle stream example, I don't see a big difference. The mixed state refers to a single copy, which might be $\rho_1,\rho_2$ or $\rho_3$. That's not the same as saying that you have all the copies you are ever going to use at the same time, which is what the tensor product state you wrote refers to. I think the content of the post doesn't reflect what you seem to be asking in the comments

Comment: @glS: My comments flesh out my question. Can you elaborate on how the ensemble description of probability for 1 particle, relates to that of N particles? The latter seems to be the 3rd form, as they are iid systems?

Comment: all relevant information should be in the post, not in the comments. You should edit the post to clarify what exactly are you asking, because I still can't tell. Are you asking what's the definition of ensemble? Or why that particular definition is used? Or are you asking what's the relation between the three states you mention? *Can you elaborate on how the ensemble description of probability for 1 particle, relates to that of N particles?* there is only one definition (which has nothing to do with particles btw) the other states are something else

Comment: "Ensemble" does not have a direct physical correspondence (in the sense of a wavefunction, or something observables), it is more a way to think about the way states are prepared, or can be interpreted.